# Looping a function through multiple .csv files in a directory using Python

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have the following code that allows me to calculate the Radial Distribution Function by input of x,y,z coordinates from a .csv file

```
import numpy as np
from RDF import RDF
import pandas as pd

# Particle setup
L = 21.1632573        #Cube side lenght
num_particles = 8000  #Number of Particles

# Calculation setup
dr = 0.1

### Parameters ###
particle_radius = 1
rMax = 10

#Import Data
x_data = pd.read_csv("test_1.csv", header=1,usecols=[0]).values
y_data = pd.read_csv("test_1.csv", header=1,usecols=[1]).values
z_data = pd.read_csv("test_1.csv", header=1,usecols=[2]).values

#Obtain float values for x,y,z
x = x_data.ravel() 
y = y_data.ravel()
z = z_data.ravel()


 # Compute pair correlation
g_r, r, reference_indices = RDF(x, y, z, L, rMax, dr)
```

Right now, the function RDF is only taking input values x,y,z from a single .csv file ("test_1.csv"). However, in the same folders I have multiple .csv files ("test_*.csv) for which I would like to extract the x,y,z coordinates and input them into the RDF function. My end goal is to obtain arrays of g_r and r for every "test_*csv" file in the directory so I can then do some statistics on them (average, standard deviation etc..).

I was able to use the following code to loop trough every files in the directory:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('test*.csv'))
for f in filenames:
    x_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[0]).values
    y_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[1]).values
    z_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[2]).values
    x = x_data.ravel()
    y = y_data.ravel()
    z = z_data.ravel()
```

However, I am now stuck on how to loop the function RDF through all the data coordinates and obtain the different g_r and r.

Comment: Your code is referring to 3 different files, `test_1.csv`, `test_2.csv`, `test_3.csv`. Is that correct?

Comment: No sorry, it is the same file, I'll edit the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you're omitting the `g_r, r, reference_indices = RDF(x, y, z, L, rMax, dr)` within your loop. Assuming you want to have this data available *after* the loop terminates, you should store these in some sort of collection object like a list or dict. I would probably use dict where key=`f` and value=`(g_r, r)`

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('test*.csv'))
output_dict = {}
for f in filenames:
    x_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[0]).values
    y_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[1]).values
    z_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[2]).values
    x = x_data.ravel()
    y = y_data.ravel()
    z = z_data.ravel()
    filenames = sorted(glob.glob('test*.csv'))
    g_r, r, reference_indices = RDF(x, y, z, L, rMax, dr)
    output_dict[f] = (g_r, r)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way however to store the output of the function into different lists or files? Ideally I'd like to have different files with g_r and r for every test.csv file

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Simply write a new file within your loop e.g. `with open(f'{f}_output.csv') as output` and write the values to file. This answer (and the other below) clearly solves the original problem *obtain the different g_r and r.* One of these should probably mark as Accepted. If you have trouble writing new files, that should be posed as a new question, not a follow-up on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the RDF function for each of the xyz data:

```
g_r_list, r_list = [], []
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('test*.csv'))
for f in filenames:
    x_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[0]).values
    y_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[1]).values
    z_data = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,usecols=[2]).values
    x = x_data.ravel()
    y = y_data.ravel()
    z = z_data.ravel()
    g_r, r, reference_indices = RDF(x, y, z, L, rMax, dr)
    g_r_list.append(g_r)
    r_list.append(r)
```